# Can KinEtre models work with Blender?

Tags: modeling, animation, bones

I don't know if you are familiar with [KinEtre](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/video/default.aspx?id=177016), software from Microsoft, but, if you are, you know that the software only allows you to work with human-like skeletons and if you have more complex armatures, like a robot, let's say, whose wheels you want to rotate, you won't be able to in KinEtre. So, do you think I can import data from KinEtre into Blender and break it apart to create an animation from it? When I say break it apart, I mean like if I am scanning a car, I would need to separate the car's wheels, so I can rotate them separately. Is this possible?

Comment: Please fix your spelling and be more clear on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what software you are talking about, but as long as you can export your object in a format that blender can read, you should be able to rework it and animate it.
For a list of supported formats see: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Once you import the model into blender you can edit it just the same as if you created the model in blender to start with.

You can select any part of the mesh while in edit mode and press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose Selection to turn the selected part into a separate object.

Another option is to use an armature and have a bone move just the vertices for the wheel, even though they are all part of the same object. This is like animating a human figure, you can move a single finger even though the entire body is one object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know KinEntre, but I've used [Brekel Kinect (free)](http://brekel.com/kinect-3d-scanner/) to export [BVH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biovision_Hierarchy) files recorded from a Kinect. The BVH files hold the motion capture data and can be imported into Blender.

Make sure that you have enabled the addon in the *User Preferences*
[image]

Note that the free version of Brekel requires installation of OpenNI which doesn't work with an installed Kinect SDK.

Scanning a car in order to animate it wouldn't work well from my experience.